# jsessionid is automatically added to URL when using selenium 2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm having one issue with Selenium 2 at the moment. The issue is that jsessionid is added to URL, like below:
http://our.server/checkout;jsessionid=755FAB46186A26192351168ABD0C3BE5?pf=115408

whereas, manual step will have below URL:
http://our.server/checkout?pf=115408

Is it a issue cause by selenium? If so, could you guys please let me know how to fix it?

BTW, I'm using Windows 7 (32 bit) and Selenium version 2.25.0.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've used Selenium for around a year and never seen anything like that so I don't think it's Selenium directly causing it.